# Viewing multiple rasters from single geopackage in QField

Tags: qfield

I'm running into an issue viewing rasters in QField with multiple rasters in a single geopackage.

I export rasters (tif, ecw) to geopackage and they open in QGIS. They're listed as "copy" in QField Sync properties. When I open the QField project, I get an "Unable to load some layers" error saying "the following layers could not be loaded, please review those and reconfigure the QGIS project".

I tried importing them into the QGIS project in different ways (add saved file to map from export dialogue, added from QGIS Browser, dragged from Windows File Explorer), none of which load in QField.

The same rasters and export settings will open in QField if I save each raster to its own geopackage.

Does this have to do with the raster export settings or how the rasters are imported in to the QGIS project?